# How to execute some code after UIView custom drawing code completes?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I am subclassing uiview and I have implemented some custom drawing code inside the Draw sub.
What I want to do is after executing the code inside the draw sub and the uiview paints itself, to execute some other code.

I am thinking to activate a timer at the end of the custom drawing code, so that the uiview paints itself and also my code executes after some milliseconds. Is this a good way to implement it?

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to do:

Calling UIView.SetNeedsDisplay() ---> UIView.Draw called ---> custom drawing code executes ---> UIView paints itself and appears on screen ---> some code executed here.

Comment: @eric: What I need is some kind of callback each time the UIView paints itself and appears on screen, so that I can execute some extra code.

Comment: Could you not post the code as to how you are drawing?

Answer (score 0):

You could post a notification (using `NSNotificationCenter`) inside the the drawInRect and register for this notification elsewhere. In this way it is more loosely coupled.

Comment: for which event should i register?

Comment: You create your own notification. The string should be unique, e.g. @"MyAppMyViewDrawingFinished"

Comment: if only two objects , i think it`s better use delegate

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could just run the code in the view's drawRect method.